# How do I make the File Explorer dropdown collapse?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I don't know the name of what I'm trying to get to collapse, so I've not been able search to solve my question. I'm sorry, so I'm going to give the excruciating long description which Google/Bing can't easily process. Here goes.

I love the new features of the File Explorer in Windows 11, with one major exception. That is the whatever-it-is-called that displays all the folders I've searched for in File Explorer, because it never closes! It will stay open for hours if I leave File Explorer open. It is in my way of doing things like sorting the list, widening/narrowing, etc. The whatever-it-is-called that displays all the folders is immediately to the right of the left arrow, then right arrow, then up arrow, the refresh. It absolutely gets in my way when using Windows. Here is a current example of the whatever-it-is-called that displays all the folders dropdown which obscures my being able to narrow/widen/etc. the listing:

[image: Example of the whatever-it-is called downdrop in this location of File Explorer]

The "D:\RodAtWork\Billy Hollis" and "D:\RodAtWork\Billy Hollis\BasicNavShell" items in the dropdown of the whatever-it-is called downdrop in this location of File Explorer, will never close. I've got to get it to close so I can continue doing what I'm trying to do, but I have no idea how to make it close. I've tried pressing the Escape key. I've tried clicking the right point chevron to no avail. I've tried right-mouse clicking File Explorer, but if there's a way of getting that whatever-it-is called downdrop in this location of File Explorer, I've not been able to discover it. Yes, I could close File Explorer, then reopen it, but that only means losing context and having to restablish it, which is tedious.

Comment: +1 clearly explained the issue.

Comment: Normally just clicking anywhere outside the folder-field should collapse the list. If this isn't happening, try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: If you search for something like "windows 11 file explorer address dropdown stays expanded" you'll find that you have joined the vast array of people (myself included) who find this bug extremely annoying. As far as I can see, there isn't a way around it, other than switching to an alternative app for managing your files. If you click in the address bar itself (to the right of any of the path) and press the Enter key on your keyboard, the dropdown usually closes, but it opens up again as soon as you sneeze!

Comment: Oh, WOW! Thank you @AvrohomYisroel for that information!! OK, it's a bug and I'll have to live with it, which isn't satisfactory, but what can you do? Is there a GitHub Issue on this or something that I can add my vote to?

Comment: @Rod See the answer (below) that I posted yesterday, as I found a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this annoying problem. You'll need to use the registry editor, so be very careful!

Start it up (press Win+R and type regedit), and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`

Look at the nodes below and check if there is one named `AutoComplete` (probably won't be there). If not, right-click the `Explorer` node and choose New -> Key. Name it `AutoComplete` and save. You'll see the new key appear under `Explorer`.

Left-click on this new key to select it, and in the right-hand pane, right-click in the blank area and choose New -> String Value. Name it `AutoSuggest`

Now double-click the `AutoSuggest` entry and enter `No` as the value.

Close any File Explorer windows you have open and re-open them.

You should find that the history dropdown works as expected, but closes immediately instead of hanging around.